# How do i iterate over rows in a data frame then append date range from 2020 to 2023 in pandas to each row

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have a simple dataframe consisting of the employee, and how much they have to hit for their sales. The column, dailytarget.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeNo':[11111,11112,11113,11115,11116,11128],
                   'OutletName':['Outlet1', 'Outlet2', 'Outlet3','Outlet4', 'Outlet5','Outlet6'],
                   'EmployeeName':['John','Tom','Bob','Sam', 'Sean', 'Zac'],
                   'TargetAmount':[1000,500,400,500,300,800]})
df
```

So i would need to add the daterange 2020 to 2023, then for each date, append the dataframe. For example,

```
(2020-01-01,11111,outlet1,Tom,$1,000)
(2020-01-02,11111,outlet1,Tom,$1,000)
(2020-01-03,11111,outlet1,Tom,$1,000)
(2020-01-04,11111,outlet1,Tom,$1,000)
.....
(2023-12-31,11111,outlet1,Tom,$1,000)
****Then move on to the next employee****
(2020-01-01,11112,outlet2,John,$500)
(2020-01-02,11112,outlet2,John,$500)
(2020-01-03,11112,outlet2,John,$500)
...
(2023-12-31,11112,outlet2,John,$500)
```

and so on for all employees. How do i do this?

I thought about getting
`pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2023-12-31')`

but i couldnt figure out how to concat or append them. Please advise thank you!

Comment: So you want to make a new row for every date between `'2020-01-01'` and `'2023-12-31'` for every employee in your existing dataframe?

Comment: Yes i do, thats possible right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thank you for formatting the question so nicely!

My guess is that you're close, but perhaps running into an error like:

`ValueError: Length of values (1461) does not match length of index (6)`

To get past this, and get your desired result I did:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeNo':[11111,11112,11113,11115,11116,11128],
                   'OutletName':['Outlet1', 'Outlet2', 'Outlet3','Outlet4', 'Outlet5','Outlet6'],
                   'EmployeeName':['John','Tom','Bob','Sam', 'Sean', 'Zac'],
                   'TargetAmount':[1000,500,400,500,300,800]})

df['date'] = pd.Series([pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2023-12-31') for x in range(df.shape[0])])
df = df.explode('date')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    EmployeeNo OutletName EmployeeName  TargetAmount       date
0        11111    Outlet1         John          1000 2020-01-01
0        11111    Outlet1         John          1000 2020-01-02
0        11111    Outlet1         John          1000 2020-01-03
0        11111    Outlet1         John          1000 2020-01-04
0        11111    Outlet1         John          1000 2020-01-05
..         ...        ...          ...           ...        ...
5        11128    Outlet6          Zac           800 2023-12-27
5        11128    Outlet6          Zac           800 2023-12-28
5        11128    Outlet6          Zac           800 2023-12-29
5        11128    Outlet6          Zac           800 2023-12-30
5        11128    Outlet6          Zac           800 2023-12-31

[8766 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Hi yes!! Exactly what i wanted, Thank you! i am still new to python so i didn't think of using the for loop that way! Appreciate your help!

Comment: I'd never thought about using the for loop in that way either, but being more experience in python means I probably knew better things to google :')